# The col output in xlrd printing something with appears to be xf formatting text. How do I get rid of this?

Tags: python, xlrd

I am using XLRD to attempt to read from and manipulate string text encapsulated within the cells of my excel document. I am posting my code, as well as the text that is returned when I choose to print a certain column.

```
import xlrd
data = xlrd.open_workbook('data.xls')
sheetname = data.sheet_names()
employees = data.sheet_by_index(0)

print employees.col(2)

>>>[text:u'employee_first', text:u'\u201cRichard\u201d', text:u'\u201cCatesby\u201d', text:u'\u201cBrian\u201d']
```

My intention is to create a dict or either reference the excel documents using strings in python. I would like to have a number of my functions in my program manipulate the data locally and then output at a later point (not within the scope of this question) to a second excel file.

How do I get rid of this extra information?

Answer (score 1):

`employees.col(2)` is a list of `xlrd.sheet.Cell` instances.  To get all the values from the column (instead of the `Cell` objects), you can use the `col_values` method:

```
values = employees.col_values(2)
```

You could also do this (my original suggestion):

```
values = [c.value for c in employees.col(2)]
```

but that is much less efficient than using `col_values`.

`\u201c` and `\u201d` are unicode left and right double quotes, respectively.  If you want to get rid of those, you can use, say, the lstrip and rstrip string methods.  E.g. something like this:

```
values = [c.value.lstrip(u'\u201c').rstrip(u'\u201d') for c in employees.col(2)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much - that was incredibly helpful. I had understood how to use  sheet.cell(x,y).value to retrieve information, but was having difficulty here. You're answer was great and I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in the values of the cells, then you should do:

`values = sheet.col_values(colx=2)`

instead of:

```
cells = sheet.col(colx=2)
values = [c.value for c in cells]
```

because it's more concise and more efficient (`Cell` objects are constructed on the fly as/when requested).