# how to take word repetition out of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, xlrd

I have a project where I have to take input values from an Excel spreadsheet and plot them with matplotlib but the values that `xlrd` returns can't be put straight into Matplotlib because the values have a string in front of it.

I'm asking how can I change the output from this:

```
  [number:150000.0, number:140000.0, number:300000.0]
```

to this:

```
  [150000.0, 140000.0, 300000.0]
```

This will allow me to put the values straight from `xlrd` into matplotlib.

Comment: Related: [The col output in xlrd printing something with appears to be xf formatting text. How do I get rid of this?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14617477/846892)

Comment: Resisting the the tempation to change the title to "how to take take word repetition out of of a list?"

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a list of strings:

```
data = ["number:150000.0", "number:140000.0", "number:300000.0"]
```

you can turn it into a list of actual `float` numbers with:

```
data = [float(item.split(":")[1]) for item in data]
```

---

**Edit** you have `Cell` objects, not strings, so use:

```
data = [cell.value for cell in data]
```

Comment: Once again Jon beat me to the punch. But he's right, this is what you want.

Comment: its saying "AttributeError: 'Cell' object has no attribute 'split'" doesnt this mean thats it not a string?

Comment: @user3415685 Yes, that is exactly what it means; I have edited my answer